# Examples of implementing Java Document model

Tags: java, swing

Does anyone have any real life use cases where someone had to make a non-trivial implementation of the Java [`Document`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Document.html) interface?

I'm looking for descriptions of the real use case, not examples of code, and not tutorials.

Comment: @DJClayworth I saw only once time good implementations for Document some code for Autocomplete JComboBox / JTextField, there really works Focus & Carret & Segment, maybe better will be stick here more infos, because in this safe_mode_form is your question too hard answerable

Comment: Do any of the known implementing classes fit your use case?

Comment: @trashgod Not the ones in the standard Java libraries. I'm looking for others.

Answer (score 2):

I did a little work for an open source MMO game known as HackWars. As part of the game I implemented an in-game chat system that ran as in InternalJFrame inside the main client. I used Document in conjunction with a JTextPane so that I could insert strings and use different fonts for different users within the same JTextPane.

The project source is hosted here: https://www.assembla.com/code/hackwars/git/nodes

The chat code starts here: https://www.assembla.com/code/hackwars/git/nodes/HWTomcatServer/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/HWChat

The specific file I used Document in was HWChat.client.chatPane which you can see the source code for here: https://www.assembla.com/code/hackwars/git/nodes/HWTomcatServer/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/HWChat/client/chatPane.java

Answer (score 2):

As part of a Java IDE I implemented an editor kit for Java source text. The document handled things like balancing brackets and quotes and auto-indenting, and also kicked off the incremental compilation process.